# Command line arguments for C++?

Tags: c++

For my assignment, it says that I am to use the command line argument ./a.out user1.txt (the text file name can change) in my main.cpp.

I have the following in my main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    string name;
    name = argv[1];
}
```

but don't know how I can get name into my BBoard setup function in BBoard cpp

```
#include "BBoard.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

User user_l;
BBoard::BBoard(){
    title = "Default BBoard";
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
}

BBoard::BBoard(const string &ttl){
    title = ttl;
}

void BBoard::setup(const string &input_file){
    ifstream fin;;
    fin.open(input_file);
    while(!fin.eof()){
        user_list.push_back(user_l);
    }
}
```

with BBoard header here

```
#ifndef BBOARD_H
#define BBOARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class User
{
public:
    User() { }

    User(const std::string& _name, const std::string& _pass)
        : name(_name), pass(_pass)
    { }

    friend bool operator==(const User& lhs, const User& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.name == rhs.name) &&
               (lhs.pass == rhs.pass);
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string pass;
};
class Message{
};
class BBoard{
private:
    string title;
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
public:
    BBoard();
    BBoard(const string &ttl);
};

#endif
```

Edit: How do I use an object in main cpp to send over name to my BBoard function?  When I try including main cpp into my board cpp, I get errors.

Comment: Another tip: never include source files; i.e don't ever do `#include "main.cpp"` or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close.  You simply need to edit your `main()` function to create a `BBoard` object, and pass the `name` to it the same way you pass `argv[1]` to `std::string`.  You can then call functions on that object, or pass that object to other functions.

---

Style advice:

What should happen if somebody forgets to pass the filename to the program?  As it stands, you crash.  It's pretty easy to tell the user what's wrong and bail if `argc` is only 1:

```
if (argc == 1) {
    cout << "usage: a.out file.txt\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Not all programmers use `using namespace std`.  There's nothing wrong with doing so in `.cpp` files, but I personally get upset when `#include`-ing a header file has the effect of calling `using namespace XXX` for me without my consent.  <strike>As it is, your header file already fully qualifies things in the `std` namespace, so you can remove that line from your header without needing to make other changes.</strike> To keep me from getting upset when I use your header, you simply need to remove `using namespace std` from the header and use `std::vector` instead of simply `vector`.

Comment: When removing using namespace in the header, he still would need to prepend the vectors with std.

Comment: I made the edits as recommended but the school testable says that my BBoard setup function is invalid with fin.open(input_file); creating problems.  Am I supposed to add const into there or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what to edit now.  :(  The error message it gives is
/tmp/testables/BBoard.cpp: In member function 'void BBoard::setup(const std::string&)': /tmp/testables/BBoard.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream >::open(const std::basic_string, std::allocator >&)' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/fstream:525: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]

Comment: @RikoKurahashi strangely, until C++11, the IOStreams objects only accpeted `char*` parameters instead of `std::string` parameters.  `fin.open(name.c_str())` should work fine.  As would just specifying the filename when creating `fin`:  `fstream fin(name.c_str());`.

In C++11 you can use `std::string` (i.e., you can drop the `.c_str()`), but to do **that** you may have to tell your compiler to accept C++11.  With GCC or Clang, you do that with `std=c++11`: `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11` (older versions of GCC required `std=c++0x`).

Comment: That message says you're passing a `std::string` to `open` while using a compiler that doesn't accept C++11.  You'll need to either pass `char*` (by calling `c_str()` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ ) or tell the compiler to accept C++11.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating an `BBoard` and then calling the `setup` function:

```
if (argc > 1) {
   string name = argv[1];
   BBoard board;
   board.setup(name);
}
```